# tk.Misc.lift(canvas) seemingly not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The full code for the chess game im making

```
import chess
#from stockfish import Stockfish
import tkinter as tk
import time

board = chess.Board()

def boardtoarr(board): #converts chess board string to 2d array
    boardlist = []
    linelist = []
    for b in range(0,128,2):
        linelist.append(str(board)[b])
        if len(linelist) == 8:
            boardlist.append(linelist)
            linelist = []
    return boardlist



#given the square of a piece on the board, returns the legal squares the piece can move to
def piecelegalmoves(square,cboard):
    ans = []
    for a in cboard.legal_moves:
        a = str(a)
        if a[0:2] == square:
            ans.append(a[2::])
    return ans

def alllegalmoves(cboard): #given a chess board it will return all legal moves
    x = str(cboard.legal_moves)[38:-2]
    x = x.split(', ')
    return x



squarevar = [] #variable to contain the starting square and the moving-to square
def squareclicked(event):
    global squarevar
    x,y = event.x,event.y
    #print(x,y)
    #print(pixeltosquare(x,y))
    #print(lsquaretocsquare(pixeltosquare(x,y)))
    #squarevar.append(lsquaretocsquare(pixeltosquare(x,y)))
    #print(squarevar)
    return lsquaretocsquare(pixeltosquare(x,y))

def highlightlegalmoves(piece,board):
    global BoardImage,redsquare
    #for widget in root.winfo_children(): #code to clear page
            #widget.destroy()
    legalmoves = piecelegalmoves(piece,board)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = BoardImage.width(), height = BoardImage.height())
    #canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = 500, height = 500)
    canvas.pack()
    for a in legalmoves:
        x = csquaretolsquare(a)
        print(x)
        pixel = topleftpixels(x[0],x[1])
        #canvas.create_image(0,0, image = redsquare, anchor = 'nw')
        canvas.create_image(pixel[1],pixel[0], image = redsquare, anchor = 'nw')
    tk.Misc.lift(canvas)

def makemoves(event): #Function to make chess moves when clicks have been inputted
    global squarevar
    squarevar.append(squareclicked(event))
    if len(squarevar) != 2:
        #print(squarevar[0])
        highlightlegalmoves(squarevar[0],board)
    if len(squarevar) == 2:
        if squarevar[1] in piecelegalmoves(squarevar[0],board): #checking if move is legal to prevent errors (input validation)
            board.push_san(squarevar[0]+squarevar[1]) #play move on backend board
            squarevar = []
            for widget in root.winfo_children(): #code to clear page
                widget.destroy()
            boardtoimage(root,str(board))
        else:
            squarevar = []
    

def topleftpixels(x,y): #returns top left pixel of given square
    return [x*100,y*100]

def pixeltosquare(x,y): #given a pixel it will return what chess square it is on
    x = ('000' + str(x))
    x = x[len(x)-3::]
    y = ('000' + str(y))
    y = y[len(y)-3::]
    return [int(y[0]),int(x[0])]

def csquaretolsquare(square): #converts chess square notation to list square notation
    ans = []
    letterorder = 'abcdefgh'
    ans.append(8-int(square[1]))
    ans.append(letterorder.index(square[0]))
    return ans

def lsquaretocsquare(square): #converts list square notation to chess square notation
    ans = ''
    letterorder = 'abcdefgh'
    ans += (letterorder[square[1]])
    ans += str(8-square[0])
    return ans 

def boardtoimage(root,boardstr): #places all pieces onto the window graphically
    global wQueen,wKing,wKnight,wBishop,wPawn,wRook,bQueen,bKing,bKnight,bBishop,bPawn,bRook,BoardImage
    LetterToImage= {
        'r': bRook, 'n': bKnight, 'b': bBishop, 'q': bQueen, 'k': bKing, 'p': bPawn,
        'R': wRook, 'N': wKnight, 'B': wBishop, 'Q': wQueen, 'K': wKing, 'P': wPawn,
    }

    boardcanvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = BoardImage.width(), height = BoardImage.height()) #This will be the canvas for the whole board, pieces and all
    boardcanvas.pack()

    boardcanvas.create_image(0,0, image = BoardImage, anchor = 'nw') #placing chess board on canvas

    #iterate through board and place piece images in correct place
    for y in range(8):
            for x in range(8):
                piece = boardtoarr(boardstr)[y][x]
                if piece in LetterToImage.keys():
                    boardcanvas.create_image(topleftpixels(x,y)[0], topleftpixels(x,y)[1], image=LetterToImage[piece], anchor="nw")
                
            

boolvar = False

def CMI_clicked(): #check if the chess menu image was clicked
    global root
    global BoardImage
    global boolvar
    for widget in root.winfo_children(): #code to clear page
            widget.destroy()
    boardtoimage(root,str(board))
    root.bind("<Button-1>", makemoves)
    


def Menu():
    global root
    global ChessMenuImage
    #Menu
    ChessMenuOption = tk.Button(root ,image = ChessMenuImage, command = CMI_clicked) #create button using chess menu image and call function 'CMI_clicked' when pressed
    ChessMenuOption.place(x = 380, y = 380) #place the chess menu image at given coordinates




root = tk.Tk()

ChessMenuImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\Chess_Selection_Image.png') #Load chess menu image file

BoardImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\ChessBoardImage.png') #Load board image file

redsquare = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\redsquare.png') #Load see-through red square file, used for showing legal moves in the GUI

#Piece image loading
#White
wQueen = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\wQueen.png')
wKing = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\wKing.png')
wPawn = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\wPawn.png')
wBishop = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\wBishop.png')
wKnight = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\wKnight.png')
wRook = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\wRook.png')

#Black
bQueen = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\bQueen.png')
bKing = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\bKing.png')
bPawn = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\bPawn.png')
bBishop = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\bBishop.png')
bKnight = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\bKnight.png')
bRook = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\benja\Documents\Python\Chess project\bRook.png')

root.geometry('800x800')

Menu()


root.mainloop()
```

specifically lines 47-61 'highlightlegalmoves' function

```
def highlightlegalmoves(piece,board):
    global BoardImage,redsquare
    #for widget in root.winfo_children(): #code to clear page
            #widget.destroy()
    legalmoves = piecelegalmoves(piece,board)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = BoardImage.width(), height = BoardImage.height())
    #canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = 500, height = 500)
    canvas.pack()
    for a in legalmoves:
        x = csquaretolsquare(a)
        print(x)
        pixel = topleftpixels(x[0],x[1])
        #canvas.create_image(0,0, image = redsquare, anchor = 'nw')
        canvas.create_image(pixel[1],pixel[0], image = redsquare, anchor = 'nw')
    tk.Misc.lift(canvas)
```

so if I run the code

```
for widget in root.winfo_children(): #code to clear page
            widget.destroy()
```

the image I get (before/after I click a piece)

before:
[image]

after (I clicked the e2 pawn):
[image]

so I know that under the original canvas its actually displaying what I want. I just what to show to lift it but its not doing that.

when I have the delete all widgets code commented, the image does not change once I click a piece, it does not display the legal moves of the piece.

Comment: It's not clear just how you were expecting this to work - is the Canvas with the legal moves supposed to somehow overlay the Canvas with the pieces?  That's impossible, all Tkinter widgets are opaque rectangles.  The reason that nothing appears, if the original Canvas is still present, is that `.pack()` will not overlap widgets - the entire window is occupied, so the new widget gets pushed outside the window.

Comment: You can draw a rectangle to highlight those legal moves.

Comment: Where  can I get images such as black and white chess?